# Use component from listener in CakePHP 4

Tags: php, cakephp, components

I'm trying to fire a flash from a listener, the listener fires correctly but the component keeps failing.

```php
$flash = new FlashComponent(new ComponentRegistry(new \Cake\Controller\Controller()));

$message = 'message';
$options = [
   'params' => [
       'title' => 'title',
       'type' => 'warning'
   ]
];

$flash->modal($message, $options);
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Event Listeners don't have access to controller components.
But you can get the current request object from the router via

```
$request = Router::getRequest();
```

Then you can get the FlashMessage Utility object via

```
$flash = $request->getFlash();
```

And finally call the flash messages you are used to from the controller via

```
$flash->info('Some info message');
```

And the flash messages should appear as you expect them.